# Alternative logging system for drupal

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I need to log some actions in Drupal. i.e: published content type of type X, deleted comment y, assigned role W to user Z etc.

It could be very easy to do this using watchdog, but i don't want to do it because i want to keep this logs without deleting rows and because i don't want to mix business actions with error logs.

I think there must be a module that does this, maybe also only an API module.

Ideally it should use a new entity to store logs and it should be integrated vith the views module.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for something similar. But I just don't see anything with that type of subscription. I did find this: http://drupal.org/project/logging_alerts . It adds e-mail logging and allows rules to add watchdog statements.

With the idea of rules a heartbeat monitor may actually do the job as well. http://drupal.org/project/heartbeat It is supposed to give you Facebook style home feeds but you can choose what is logged to it with rules so it will only log node creation info etc.

Just some thoughts that I was going through when I stumbled upon this question in google.